# Propose ASPX source file formatter/beautifier, please

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have web project with file like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="XXX" Inherits="XXX" ValidateRequest="false"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>
<%   
string XXX = Request.Form["XXX"];
string XXX = Request.Form["XXX"];
etc...
```

I'd like to format it. How can I do it? Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio there's an option to Format Whole Document.

Use the following keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl + E</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>

Or from the menu: *Edit->Advanced->Format Document*

Comment: In the default settings for 2008 Ctrl+E, D and Ctrl+E, Ctrl+D and Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D run the same command. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, go to Edit/Advanced/Format Document

Answer (score 1):

You could use Visual Studio's Key-Shortcut: <kbd>CTRL + A</kbd> (to select all), <kbd>CTRL + K</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> also works to format the current file without the select all required.